# C++ integer conversion rules

Tags: c++, type-conversion

What are the rules used by C++ to determine the type of an arithmetic expression involving two different integer types?

In general it is easy to work out the outcome, however I have come across cases with signed/unsigned ints that are confusing.

For example both the below come out as `unsigned int` in VS.

```
unsigned int us = 0;
int s = 1;

auto result0 = us - s; // unsigned int
auto result1 = s - us; // unsigned int
```

Is this the same for other compilers? Are there any specific rules for determining the type?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)?

Comment: The rules are the same as for template type deduction, except in the case `auto x{expr};` / `auto x = {expr};`.

Comment: This almost seems more like a question of type promotion then auto deduction.

Comment: You need to read about [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), especially [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions).

Comment: I rewrote your question since I don't think you're asking about `auto`. Feel free to undo if you disagree with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all well-defined.

`1` is a *signed* literal. In fact, if you wanted it `unsigned`, you'd need to use hexadecimal or octal notation, an appropriate suffix (for example `u`), or a cast.

If an arithmetic operation is encountered that has a `signed int` and an `unsigned int` as arguments, then the `signed int` is *converted* to an `unsigned int` type.

Comment: All the details of integral conversion depend on the destination type, but when this is auto it is unknown?

Comment: "All the details of integral conversion depend on the destination type". Absolutely that is **never** the case.

Comment: No, you're misinterpreting what that states. `us - s` is an expression with a distinct type, irrespective of what you are assigning it to, if anything. Are you talking about compile time evaluable constant expressions?

Comment: @JemTucker the destination type is the type to which another type is converted. In this example the destination type is `unsigned int`. The destination type has nothing to do with the type of the operand on the left hand side of the assignment and therefore nothing to do with `auto`.

Comment: @JemTucker: It might be an idea to read up on "compile time evaluable constant expressions", "type deduction", the link you've already posted, then re-ask a question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short, rough answer, I hope it is useful even though it does not cover everything and may even be an oversimplification:

1. Literals are signed unless specified as 'U'.
2. In an integral expressions involving different types, the smaller integer types are promoted (to int if all involved types would fit in int, otherwise promotion to unsigned int), so when an unsigned and a signed value e.g. are added, the signed value is 'promoted' to unsigned int if the unsigned variable is of same bit width as an int. So an unsigned int is regarded by the compiler as 'larger' than a signed int in the promotion rules, even if during runtime the actual values stored in the variables would easily fit into a signed representation of same number of bits.
3. Note also that 'char' may mean unsigned char, while 'int' always means signed int.

Comment: 3. Not the whole story, char, unsigned char and signed char are 3 distinct types. The C standard guarantees that all members of the basic execution character set have non-negative values. Editing answer.