# Why logical operation is not working properly if i use string::size()

Tags: c++, string

```
string s;
cin >>s ; //input string is: a 
int i=1; 
if(i < s.size()-3 ) cout <<"Yes"<<endl; 
else cout << "No"<<endl;
```

If the input string is `a` then output should be `No` but compiler is showing `Yes`.

```
int i = 1;
int len = s.size()-3;
if(i < len ) cout <<"Yes"<<endl;
else cout << "No"<<endl;
```

If I use the `len` variable then it is working fine. Now the output is showing `No`.

Comment: have you had a look at the documentation? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size
look at the type and then go check how unsigned math works. You should be able to find your answer ;)

Comment: `s.size()-3` is only sensible if `s.size()` is ≥3.

Comment: The only reason it "works" is because you are ignoring a warning the compiler is emitting and then converts your `len` to a negative value. Always fix your warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s.size()` returns an **unsigned** type.

Since `s.size()` is `1` in your example, `unsigned(1)-3` will wrap to a *very large* positive value. Thus:

```
int i=1; 
if(i < s.size()-3)
```

compares a *signed* `i` to an *unsigned* value, and so will implicitly convert the value of `i` to *unsigned* and evaluate the `if` as `true` since `1` is less than that large positive value.

Whereas:

```
int len = s.size()-3;
```

will convert the large *unsigned* positive value into a *signed negative* value, thus:

```
int i=1;
if(i < len)
```

compares two *signed* values, and will evaluate the `if` as `false` since `1` is not less than a negative value.

Comment: It would be good to add a link to why conversions happen.  Here's one, maybe you have a better one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35178031/5987

Answer (score 1):

`s.size()` returns an `unsigned int`, so if `s.size() < 3` then `s.size() - 3` becomes very big positive integer. So it can be possible.